# How to configure jenkins for checkstyle for php project

Tags: php, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-php

Getting start with jenkin for php project.

the following steps has been configured
1)Download jenkin-1.549
2)installed php plugin checkstyle
3)Add a project sample zf2demo

build.xml in zf2 demo

```
<target name="phpcs" >
  <exec executable="phpcs">
    <arg line="--report=checkstyle 
 --report-file=${project.basedir}/build/logs/checkstyle.xml
 --standard=Zend
 ${project.basedir}/*.php" />
  </exec>
 </target>
```

phpcs.xml in zf2demo/build

```
<ruleset name="zenddemo">
 <description>Description of your coding standard</description>

 <rule ref="Generic.PHP.DisallowShortOpenTag"/>
 <!-- ... -->
</ruleset>
```

The build run successfully
**Errors
    No report files were found. Configuration error?**

Where to configure report file? do we need to create it manually

anything more need to configure to generate report?

In configuration part add
**Post-build Actions
Publish Checkstyle analysis results**

```
Checkstyle results
```

‘/build/checkstyle.xml’ doesn’t match anything: ‘’ exists but not ‘/build/checkstyle.xml’

how to configure these?
**Edited**
When run from the console [image]

Answer (score 0):

Go to build and check Console output [raw]
What is the result of phpcs? Any errors?

```
phpcs:
     [exec] Result: 1
```

If you run phpcs fron console directly with provided params does report file generated?

Comment: FILE: C:\wamp\www\zenddemo\index.php
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
FOUND 2 ERROR(S) AFFECTING 2 LINE(S)
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 1 | ERROR | End of line character is invalid; expected "\n" but found "\r\n"
 2 | ERROR | Missing file doc comment
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------- check for one file index.php the result i get from console is as above

Comment: You should run phpcs with all options from build config, i.e. -- report, --report-file, --standard=Zend. And check if reportfile is created

Comment: report file is generating correctly through command line. in Checkstyle results configuration whether we need to define any file path? in project configuration or anything like that i am missing

Comment: do we need to create a checkstyle.xml by our self? and tell the path? how will be the format for checkstyle.xml

Comment: Use ${basedir} instead of ${project.basedir}. checkstyle.xml should be genereated by phpcs as you provide option --report-file=${basedir}/build/logs/checkstyle.xml

Publish Checkstyle analysis result in postbuild acton should be 'build/logs/checkstyle.xml'